# A blue die and a red die are rolled - events A-F shows the following:

Tags: probability

**A: The red die shows even number** (27/36...I think?)

**B: The blue die shows odd number** (also 27/36, I believe)

**C: The sum of the face numbers is 6** (5/36)

**D: The sum of the face numbers is 9** (4/36)

**E: At least one die shows 2** (Not sure, but I think it's 11/36)

**F: The difference of 2 faces is one.** (Not sure, but I think it's 6/36)

I need to find (P=probability):

**(a) P(A and B)**

-For this one, I'm not sure if I got the probabilities (above) right, so I got 18/36.

**(b) P(F and D)**

-I got 1/36

**(c) P(E or F)**

-I got 14/36, not sure if it's correct

**(d) P(F given E)**

**(e) P(A given E)**

Now, for the conditional probabilities (d and e), I have no idea how to do. What is your approach to getting the answers to the conditional probabilities? Also, can someone make sure the answers I got were correct, and if not, explain why it isn't correct for future reference?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A)=P(B)=18/36=1/2$ because there are $36$ possibilities and $18$ of those have red showing even and $18$ have blue showing odd.

$P(C)$, $P(D)$, and $P(E)$ are correct.

$P(F)=10/36=5/18$ because $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,5),(5,4),(4,3),(3,2),(2,1)$ are all of the possibilities of having a difference of $1$ between the two dice.

(a) $P(A\cap B)=9/36$ because the red die can only be $2,3,4$ and the blue die can only be $1,3,5$, so there are $3^2=9$ possibilites of having both $A$ and $B$.

(b) $P(F\cap D)=2/36=1/18$ because, as seen in the enumeration above when calculating $P(F)$, only $(4,5)$ and $(5,4)$ sum to $9$ and have a difference of $1$.

(c) $P(E\cup F) = P(E)+P(F)-P(E\cap F)$. Now $P(E\cap F)=4/36=1/9$ by again looking at the enumeration when calculating $P(F)$.

For conditional probabilities, you want to use the definition
$$ P(X \mid Y) = \frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}.$$

(d) $P(F \mid E) = \frac{P(F\cap E)}{P(E)}$. We have already found both $P(E\cap F)$ and $P(E)$, so this one is easy.

(e) $P(A \mid E) = \frac{P(A\cap E)}{P(E)}$. We know $P(E)$, so we need only compute $P(A\cap E)$. I'll let you do this.

Comment: Just to clarify - does P(Y∩X) = P(X∩Y)? For d I got 4/11 and for e I got 5/11.

Comment: Yes, for any two sets, $X\cap Y=Y\cap X$. Your (d) is correct, but (e) is incorrect. Enumerating rolls that are in both $A$ and $E$, we get:
$$(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(4,2),(6,2).$$
Thus $P(A\cap E)=8/36=2/9$, which gives that $P(A\mid E)=8/11$.

Comment: At least my post helped John, that's nice =)

Answer (score 1):

**A : The red die shows even number.**

This event concerns only the red die and is indeed independant of the blue die hence :

$$P(A) = {3\over 6} = {1\over 2}$$

**B : The blue die shows odd number.**

For the same reasons as event $A$ :

$$P(B) = {1\over 2}$$

**C : The sum of the face numbers is $6$.**

Here we can solve this by enumerating the number of relevant events over the total number of possible events.

Here are the $(blue, red)$ events that satisfiy $blue + red = 6$ :

$$(1,5) , (2,4), (3,3), (4,2),(5,1)$$

We can see there are $5$ different cases that satisfy the condition and we know that the total number of combinations is $36$ so we can conclude :

$$P(C) = {5\over 36}$$

**D : The sum of the face numbers is 9**

Same as $C$, answer is :

$$P(D) = {4\over 36}$$

**E : At least one die shows $2$**

Let's enumerate the possibilities :

$$(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(1,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2)$$

So $$P(E)={11\over 36}$$

**F : The difference of two face is one.**

Again we enumerate favorable rolls :

$$(1,2),(2,1)(2,3),(3,2)(3,4),(4,3)(4,5),(5,4),(5,6),(6,5)$$

So :

$$ P(F) = {10\over 36} $$

**(a) $P(A\cap B)$**

Since we saw that $A$ and $B$ are independant events, we have :

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)*P(B) = {1\over 4}$$

**(b) $P(F\cap D)$**

Let's look at the couples that satisfy $D$ :

$$(3,6),(4,5),(5,4),(6,3)$$

We can see that only $(4,5)$ and $(5,4)$ satisfy $F$ so :

$$P(F\cap D) = {2\over 36} = {1\over 18}$$

**(c) $P(E\cup F)$**

For this we can apply the formula :

$$P(E\cup F) = P(E)+P(F)-P(E\cap F)$$

We have $P(E) = {11\over 36}$, $P(F) = {10\over 36}$ and we can see that $P(E\cap F) = {4\over 36}$ because $E\cap F$ is satisfied by the four events : $(2,1),(2,3),(1,2),(3,2)$

So we have :

$$P(E\cup F) = {11+10-4\over 36}={17\over 36}$$

**(d) $P(F|E)$**

We can use the following formula :

$$P(F|E) = {P(F\cap E)\over P(E)} = {{4\over 36}\over {11\over 36} }= {4\over 36}*{36\over 11} = {4\over 11}$$

**(e) $P(A|E)$**

Same thing : $$P(A|E) = {P(A\cap E)\over P(E)}$$

We can again enumerate the cases that satisfy $A\cap E$ :

$$(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(4,2),(6,2)$$

So $P(A\cap E) = {8\over 36}$

And :$$P(A|E) = {{8\over 36}\over {11\over 36}} = {8\over 36}*{36\over 11} = {8\over 11}$$